# How can I get LOGON_USER info from windows auth without having the username password prompt appear?

Tags: node.js, authentication, iis, windows-server, iisnode

I am using iisnode to run my express, nodejs application on Windows Server 2016. I only need the LOGON_USER (username) of the client computer connecting to my app (This is on a company network). When connecting to my app it prompts the user for username password. My understanding is when using windows authentication I can access the clients credentials without having them login to my app since they have already logged on to their computer?

I have disabled anonymous authentication and enabled Windows authentication in IIS on my app under Default Web Site. I have followed [these instructions](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/87) to promote some server variable ex. LOGON_USER. When I brows to my apps site I am prompted with the login and username popup. What do I have to to to get access to the clients username/computer name without having them provide their credentials again. I don't even need to have them authenticated I just need the username from the computer they are accessing my app from.

web.config.

```
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <!-- Remove the modules element if running on IIS 8.5-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <!-- <httpErrors existingReponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors> -->

    <iisnode node_env="%node_env%" 
                nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1" 
                maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024" 
                maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100" 
                namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250" 
                maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512" 
                maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000" 
                asyncCompletionThreadCount="0" 
                initialRequestBufferSize="4096" 
                maxRequestBufferSize="65536" 
                uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000" 
                gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000" 
                loggingEnabled="true" logDirectory="iisnode"
                debuggingEnabled="true" d
                ebugHeaderEnabled="false" 
                debuggerPortRange="5058-6058" 
                debuggerPathSegment="debug" 
                maxLogFileSizeInKB="128" 
                maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
                maxLogFiles="20" 
                devErrorsEnabled="true" 
                flushResponse="false" 
                enableXFF="false" 
                promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE,LOGON_USER,REMOTE_USER,REMOTE_HOST" 
                configOverrides="iisnode.yml" 
                watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" 
                nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />

    <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server/dist/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
            <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^server/dist/index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
            </rule>

            <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
            <rule name="StaticContent" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <action type="Rewrite" url="client/build/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <match url="*.*" />
            </rule>

            <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server/dist/index.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh...Figured it out. I was using the ip address for my site http://ip.address/myapp. It will always prompt for login and password if the url has periods in it. So I canged the ip to the server name and it cleared up the problem. http://myservername/myapp